# Largest base $b$ such that sum of digits of base $b$ of $11^4$ do not add up to $16$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When $11^4$ is written out in base $10$, the sum of its digits is $16=2^4$. What is the largest base $b$ such that the base-$b$ digits of $11^4$ do not add up to $2^4$?

Is there an elegant solution? I tried plugging in bases, but this obviously does not work. I am thinking Binomial Theorem, but I am not sure how that will translate to other bases.

Comment: I am not to sure myself. The question is a bit ambiguous in of itself.

Comment: Okay, I see.  You got this question and you interpreted it incorrectly.  The question is asking when the number $(11_b)^4=(10b + 1)^2$ has digits that add up to $16_{10}$.  It isnt asking about the number $(11_{10})^4 = 14641_{10}$ when written in other bases.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are asking about $11_b^4$ in base $b$, the largest is base $6$, where
$11_6^4=7^4_{10}=15041_6$ with a digit sum of $11_{10}$ or $15_6$

If we don't worry about carries, we have $11^4=14641$ in any base.  This comes from $(b+1)^4=b^4+4b^3+6b^2+4b+1$.  It is only when the $6$ carries that the sum will not be $16_{10}$

Comment: Does base 7 not work? It equals $60454_7$, and 8 works as well: $34461_8$? Can I have some clarification please?

Comment: @djdumpling:  you are not taking $11_b$ in base $b$.  You are taking $11$ in base $10$ to the fourth power.  I do not think that is what the question is asking.  For bases greater than $14641, 11_{10}^4$ has only one digit, so the digit sum is $14641_{10}$.  There is no greatest base where the sum is not $16$ in that reading.

Comment: $11_{10}^4$ will have entirely different digits based on the base and there is really no point that I can see in asking which of them add to $16_{10}$ (the digits add to $18$ in base $9$, to $1$ in base $11$ and $22$ in base $12$).  Of course that doesn't mean one *can't* ask (I'm not sure there is another base where they add to 16 but there could be) but I doubt that is what the OP intends.

Comment: Oh, you *are* the OP.  Never mind.  But there is no largest base where they don't add to $16$.   the number is $14641_{10}$ and in bases equal or larger to $14641$ it will be a single digit that has the value $14641$ which is greater than $16$.  But sure why you thought this would settle down to $16$.  It's not sixteen for the bases less than $10$ or slightly more than $10$ so why should it equal $16$ in general?

Comment: @fleablood:  As revelationnow says, the digits of $11_{10}^4$ expressed in base $14626$ add to $16_{10}$.  I don't think this is interesting, but it is true.  It is clearly the last base they sum to $16$ but the original question asked about bases where the digits do not sum to $16$

Comment: @RossMillikan well, that is certainly logical.  I suppose a question "what are all the bases in which the digits to the number $14641_{10}$ add to $16$" would be interesting as an exercise in critical thinking. But the result wouldn't be interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Answer appears to be any base >14626.

$$
11^4_{10} = 14641_{10}
$$
$$
11^4_{14626} = 1F_{14626}
$$

Sum of digits in base 14626 appears to be 16. All bases higher than that have a different sum for the digits.

Comment: First of all the sum  of binary digits is $7$. Second, this does not answer the question.

Comment: It asks for the largest base such that the digits do not add to 16. There are larger bases than 2.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the obvious stupidities.

Comment: No, $11^4_{14626}=14641_{14626}$,  As I said in my answer, this comes from expanding $(b+1)^4$  This is true in any base higher than $6$.

Comment: I reinterpreted the question (after my initial misinterpretation) as asking about sum of digits of $11^4$ upon conversion to a certain base b from base 10. Perhaps my notation is incorrect in that $11^4_{14626}$ doesn't represent what I intended to show, and is incorrectly assuming the base conversion.

Comment: We were asked for a base where the digits do not add to $16$.  If you take $14641_{10}$ and express it in base $14626$ you get digits worth $1$ and $15_{10}$, which do sum to $16$.  I still think the $11$ is in the base of interest, not in base $10$